# Checking if filename exists in current directory

Tags: perl, filecompare

I have a script that I am trying to modify so that depending on the location its executed from, it will be checking to see if there is a file with the name **regression_user.rpt** and if so, it will make a new file called **regression_user1.rpt**. I've found solutions but Im not sure how to change it to do what I want.

What I have is the following:

```
my $filename = 'c:\temp\test.txt';
if(-e $filename){
   //Create file with new name
   print("File $filename exists\n");
}else{
   //Create base file
   print("File $filename does not exists\n");
}
```

Except, the path for `$filename` is variable. Is there a way to incorporate the execution location as a variable into this check?

The purpose of this is to make sure I dont overwrite existing files (has happened one too many times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by execution location you mean the current work directory, all you need is the following:

```
my $filename = 'test.txt';
```

If by execution location you mean the directory in which the script being executed is found, you can use the following:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $filename = "$RealBin/test.txt";
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I didnt know if I HAD to put a path or not, since the file and script are in different directories but loaded through some modules.

Comment: `test.txt` *is* a path. It refers to `text.txt` in the current directory. Path's don't need to have a directory component.